# How to create an interface using scala

Tags: eclipse, scala, interface

I am developing a spark application in eclipse ide with scala language and with maven dependencies. 
I would like to know: 
Is it possible to create an interface that has a text area and a button with scala language on eclipse? 
I know how to manipulate Java GUI. But I have no idea how to manipulate Scala GUI.
I'm still new to this apache Spark environment

Comment: I don't think you know what is Apache Spark. I would suggest you be as clear as possible with your question. And as for your question; There are multiple ways to create GUI apps using Scala. All of them don't even remotely depend on Eclipse or Apache Spark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to do that in Scala but it has no relation to the Apache Spark Environment. The latter is an execution framework, specifically a distributed general-purpose cluster-computing (aka grid computing) framework which is not something you'd use to write UIs on. To create UIs you'd need a UI framework. One option is to look at ScalaFX (http://www.scalafx.org/).

Of course, it can be useful to have a UI to visualize minimally inputs/outputs of your apache-backed computation layer, I suspect that's why you asked the question, but they are not otherwise related. Hope this helps.